# How to receive sms via smpp connection - Kannel

Tags: smpp, kannel

I sent messages through smpp connection (using selenium SmppSim) from Kannel and it worked.
But somehow when I try to receive messages or in other words when I try to send messages from SmppSim It doesn't work. The MO messages of the SmppSim queue into the MO-queue.

I tried these things.

1. Used same port for send and receive (Kannel/SmppSim).
2. Used different ports for send and receive (Kannel/SmppSim).
3. Two groups for same smsc-smpp for send and receive. (It may be wrong)

Now I'm using port 2775 for send and port 2776 for receive.

```
#kannel.conf
group=smsc
smsc=smpp
....
port = 2775
receive-port = 2776
transceiver-mode = true
....
```

In SmppSim

```
#smppsim.props
SMPP_PORT=2775
....
SYSTEM_IDS=smppclient
PASSWORDS=password
OUTBIND_ENABLED=true
OUTBIND_ESME_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
OUTBIND_ESME_PORT=2776
OUTBIND_ESME_SYSTEMID=smppclient
OUTBIND_ESME_PASSWORD=password
....
```

When I run the bearerbox, it shows like below. (sms send is working)

```
....
connect failed
System error 111: Connection refused
ERROR: error connecting to server `localhost' at port `2776'
SMPP[SMPPSim]: Couldn't connect to server.
SMPP[SMPPSim]: Couldn't connect to SMS center (retrying in 10 seconds).
....
```

How do I configure this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Please read SMPP v3.4 specification, part 2.2.1.

> The purpose of the outbind operation is to allow the SMSC signal an ESME to originate a
>   bind_receiver request to the SMSC.

So it's used for SMSC (SMPPSim) to connect to ESME (Kannel) and request for callback connection.

However you can run few SMPPSim instances listening on different ports. Each instance should use own configuration file this case.